# mariadb sec_to_time only displays up to 23:59:59

Tags: time, mariadb

I'm using:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.14-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

and if I do queries like these:

```
select sec_to_time(timestampdiff(SECOND, '2018-05-31T00:00:00', '2018-06-01T00:00:01'))
union all
select sec_to_time(24*60*60+1)
```

The result always is '00:00:01' instead of '24:00:01'

Am I doing something wrong or is this a (known) bug?

Comment: Hmmm...  I get `24:00:01` from Mariadb 10.2.15, 10.2.2, 10.3.7, Percona 5.6.22, Oracle 5.7.15, and a few others.  And I see nothing in the changelog to indicate that it was fixed recently.

Comment: Seems it is a display issue in my used tool: DbVisualizer. Tried it on commandline and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out, that this is a "display issue".

Running

```
select sec_to_time(timestampdiff(SECOND, '2018-05-31T00:00:00', '2018-06-01T00:00:01'))
```

in mysql/mariadb commandline tool gives '24:00:01'

When run on the same DB via DbVisualizer it gives '00:00:01'.

This is just a display issue as sorting works:

```
select sec_to_time(timestampdiff(SECOND, '2018-05-31T00:00:00', '2018-06-01T00:00:01'))
union all
select sec_to_time(timestampdiff(SECOND, '2018-05-31T00:00:01', '2018-06-01T00:00:01'))
union all
select sec_to_time(timestampdiff(SECOND, '2018-05-31T00:00:02', '2018-06-01T00:00:01'))
union all
select sec_to_time(timestampdiff(SECOND, '2018-06-01T00:00:00', '2018-06-01T00:00:01'))
```

order by 1

will happily display

```
00:00:01
23:59:59
00:00:00
00:00:01
```

Sorry…

Comment: Hmmm...  I get `24:00:01, 24:00:00, 23:59:59, 00:00:01` on 5.6.22 and 10.3.7 via commandline tool.

Comment: That's what I said, @RickJames

Comment: ResultSet.getString will give you correct string, and not JDBC Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Asking the DbVis experts I got the solution.

The JDBC Driver returns the result as a time object.

The commandline interface returns it as a CHAR object.

Casting to CHAR displays the same result as the commandline interface does.